# Upload ByteArrayInputStream to FTP in Java

Tags: java, csv, ftp

I am using Apache common net for uploading a file to FTP server. The problem is: I have a string to write in CSV file and I want to upload it to FTP server. I dont want to store the file on local, so I do as following:

```
FTPClient ftpclient = new FTPClient();
try {
    String csvContent = ".......";
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(csvContent .getBytes());
    ftpclient.connect(ftpServer);
    ftpclient.login(user, password);
    ftpclient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    ftpclient.changeWorkingDirectory(directory);
    ftpclient.storeFile("test.csv", is);
    System.out.println(ftpclient.getReplyCode());
    ftpclient.logout();
}
```

The method `ftpclient.getReplyCode()` always returns error 550 "test.csv": No such file or directory.

Could you help me to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Try adding `ftpclient.enterLocalPassiveMode();` before the transfer